# NSUserDefaults returns null in NSNotificationCenter selector

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nsnotificationcenter

I have the following code to register an observer:

```
// This logs some value
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"]); 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNotifications:)
                                             name:SomeNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void) handleNotifications: (NSNotification *)notification
{
  // This logs null
  NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"]); 
}
```

Why is `myKey` returning null in the notification selector?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to save a new value when the value does not exists in the selector, however it always appear to return null in the selector after the app is restarted.

```
- (void) handleNotifications: (NSNotification *)notification
{

  if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"])) {
    NSLog(@"Saving");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"ABC", forKey:@"myKey"]
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
  }
}
```

Comment: To solve your problem we need more info

Comment: I think you need to do a little reading into what `return` actually does.

Comment: I'm... shocked that this code even compiles. That return isn't remotely close to right.

Comment: the OP fixed all his 'typos' ... the bug seems to remain

Comment: If I change the key, it does work correctly. Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that evidently you do not have any object stored into the `standardUserDefaults` for the key `@"myKey"` at the time that `-handleNotifications:` is called and `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"]` returns `nil`.

Are you handling other notifications besides `SomeNotification` in `-handleNotifications:`?  If so, you may be entering `-handleNotifications:` before the lines

```
// This logs some value
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"]); 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNotifications:)
                                             name:SomeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

execute.

Comment: This is the only notification that is happening. 

The code block is part of AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, it prints out some value for `@"myKey"`, however when the notification fires later, it returns `nil`. 

Hoever, a straightforward `NSUserDefaults` saves outside a notification selector or a completion block works.

Comment: I manually tested via `postNotification` and it did work. 

So it looks like Facebook notification: `FBSessionDidBecomeOpenActiveSessionNotification` is causing the problem when the session is being opened. `@"myKey"` returns `nil` in the selector for handling `FBSessionDidBecomeOpenActiveSessionNotification`

Comment: Looks like I made a silly mistake in my code. I was removing the value somewhere in the selector. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NoraOlsen Glad to help.  Was the answer correct that another notification (`FBSessionDidBecomeOpenActiveSessionNotification`) was being posted and handled in your `-handleNotifications:` method?  In general, exceptional circumstances aside, it is good practice to use separate methods for separate notifications.

Comment: Not really. Currently, I only have 1 notification handler for the `FBSessionDidBecomeOpenActiveSessionNotification`. 

There was a bug in the code that removes the saved value prior to opening the session. After the session completes and the handler saves the new value. 

Therefore, when the app restarts, the value will exist.